# os.rename python socket OSError: [WinError 10038] an operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

Tags: python, operating-system, rename, listdir

I need to rename a file, that was previously downloaded, so I dont have the exact filename. This was my approach:

```
   for file in os.listdir("./"):
       if file.endswith(".mp3"):
           os.rename(file, "song.mp3")
```

I get this error:

```
OSError: [WinError 10038] an operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

full error message:

```
(flashmich) C:\Users\user\Desktop\python\Flashmich>python FlashMich.py
[youtube] 7h7ntYLLrfQ: Downloading webpage
[download] Destination: Mark Forster - Kogong-7h7ntYLLrfQ.webm
[download] 100% of 3.53MiB in 01:02
[ffmpeg] Destination: Mark Forster - Kogong-7h7ntYLLrfQ.mp3
Deleting original file Mark Forster - Kogong-7h7ntYLLrfQ.webm (pass -k to keep)
Mark Forster - Kogong-7h7ntYLLrfQ.mp3
Exception in voice thread Thread-9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\python\Flashmich\lib\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 603, in run
    self._do_run()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\python\Flashmich\flashmich\lib\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 596, in _do_run
    play_audio(data, encode=not self.source.is_opus())
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\python\Flashmich\flashmich\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 638, in send_audio_packet
    self.socket.sendto(packet, (self.endpoint_ip, self.voice_port))
OSError: [WinError 10038] Ein Vorgang bezog sich auf ein Objekt, das kein Socket ist
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000172C7D8D820>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

I am not dealing with any sockets so I am really confused

(I am working in a virtual env if that is important)

Comment: at first glance, I wonder if this is maybe arising from other parts of your code.  Could you provide a stack trace (the full error output), please?

Comment: The original error contains some german (idk why) but I'll update the question

Comment: You seem to be using the discord api and it's using sockets (because it's an api) so the error is most likely related to your discord code

Comment: The error you are seeing is coming from code other than what you posted here.  The culprit is that `self.socket.sendto` call.  Sorry, it's hard to give any more useful info from my perspective, but hope it at least helps you shift focus.

Comment: What made you think the error was caused by `os.rename()`?  That function is not mentioned anywhere in the error traceback...

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see which file makes problem. I guess - you renamed file which is still downloaded - so socket can't save rest of file. OR you renamed file which discord is sending and socket has problem to read rest of file.